# split string in powershell using delimiter

Tags: powershell, split, substring, delimiter

i have the below powershell script:

```
$hostNames = "10.130.68.77, 172.29.207.33, ###, gcsl-blg7v=10.130.68.77, ndtv23v0675=172.29.207.33"
$iplist = $hostNames.Split(', ###, ')[0]
$dnsiplist = $hostNames.Split(', ###, ')[1]

Write-Host "COMPLETE LIST: $hostNames"
Write-Host "IP LIST: $iplist"
Write-Host "DNS-IP LIST: $dnsiplist"
```

Output:

```
COMPLETE LIST: 10.130.68.77, 172.29.207.33, ###, gcsl-blg7v=10.130.68.77, ndtv23v0675=172.29.207.33
IP LIST: 10.130.68.77
DNS-IP LIST:
```

i wish to split on ', ###, ' so that i could get the below desired output:

```
COMPLETE LIST: 10.130.68.77, 172.29.207.33, ###, gcsl-blg7v=10.130.68.77, ndtv23v0675=172.29.207.33
IP LIST: 10.130.68.77, 172.29.207.33
DNS-IP LIST: gcsl-blg7v=10.130.68.77, ndtv23v0675=172.29.207.33
```

Please let me know how can i?

Comment: I'd split on the comma and concatenate the pieces I need by their index.  ‍♂️

Comment: The `.Split()` method might not work as you think it does. You may try the `-split` operator instead. ☝  .... `($hostNames -Split ', ###, ')[0]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.Split` uses the `public string[] Split(params char[] separator);` overload by default, in your example this means that the `', ###, '` is first converted to a char array `[char[]] ', ###, '` and then split by each char. You need to help PowerShell to use the correct overload,  `public string[] Split(string[] separator, StringSplitOptions options);`:

```bash
$hostNames = '10.130.68.77, 172.29.207.33, ###, gcsl-blg7v=10.130.68.77, ndtv23v0675=172.29.207.33'
$iplist, $dnsiplist = $hostNames.Split([string[]] ', ###, ', [System.StringSplitOptions]::None)

Write-Host "COMPLETE LIST: $hostNames"
Write-Host "IP LIST: $iplist"
Write-Host "DNS-IP LIST: $dnsiplist"
```

Note that this issue only happens in Windows PowerShell (.NET Framework), in PowerShell 7+ `$hostNames.Split(', ###, ')` would work just fine.

It would be easier to use the regex-based [`-split`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_split?view=powershell-7.2) operator in this case:

```bash
$hostNames = '10.130.68.77, 172.29.207.33, ###, gcsl-blg7v=10.130.68.77, ndtv23v0675=172.29.207.33'
$iplist, $dnsiplist = $hostNames -split ', ###, '

Write-Host "COMPLETE LIST: $hostNames"
Write-Host "IP LIST: $iplist"
Write-Host "DNS-IP LIST: $dnsiplist"
```